# Is this function differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Is the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
e^x & \text{if $x<0$,} \\[2ex]
x+1 & \text{if $x\ge 0$}
\end{cases}$$
differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: First decide what the derivative would be if it existed. Then go back to the definition of derivative and see whether that value satisfies the definition at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The left derivative is $(e^x)' = e^x$ which is $1$ at the point $x=0$.
The right derivative is $(x+1)' = 1$ which is still equal to $1$ at the point $x=0$.
Since these two values are equal, yes, the derivative exists at $x=0$ and its value is $1$.

Comment: This is insufficient. Continuity must first be determined.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 If the function has a derivative, this implies it's also continuous, no?

Comment: Suppose the function was $x+2$. Your argument could be employed with that as well, since the right derivative of $x+2$ at $x=0$ is $1$. However, then the function would not be differentiable.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 OK, true, I see.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see whether a function is differentiable at any point, first you must check its continuity. Here it is continuous. Value of the function is 1.

Left hand derivative must be equal to the right hand derivative. Here it is also equal to 1. You can see it by differentiating.

Comment: When you say 'its continuity' do you mean the continuity of the derivative or the function, because the later is false.

Comment: @AliCaglayan: I did mean the continuity of the function and I believe it is continuous. $e^x$ when $x$ is tending to $0$ is $1$ and $x+1$ at $x=0$ is also $1$. So the function is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you take the tangent at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ of $y=f(x)$, where $f$ is differentiable, the fonction $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if $x<x_0$,} \\[2ex]
f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+y_0 & \text{if $x\ge x_0$}
\end{cases}$$ will be differentiable at $x=x_0$